# WebService Authentication with Soap Header

Tags: java, web-services, http, soap

Hope you can help me here.
I need to get authentication from a request to a WebService and then act according to the validation of this credentials. Now I am achieving it with get`(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);`. Do you know a way of using the Soap Header instead of Http Header ? Hope you do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SOAP-UI tool (Must have tool for web service developers)
 then you can use it for giving Authentication information.
There is Tab on bottom side of request where you can give values in header.
Then using TCP-IP monitor you can check the actual request coming in 
and you can see how to give those values in SOAP Headers.